# Spark application terminating with exit code 137

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, opencv

I am running a Scala application that tries to perform Object Recognition using Spark. I state that I am new to both Spark and Object Recognition, so it's probable that I may encounter issues due to suboptimal programming.

Whenever I try to run my application I get numerous instances of the following error:

```
24/03/10 11:17:08 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 81) (slave-1 executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container from a bad node: container_1708797483663_0062_01_000014 on host: slave-1. Exit status: 137. Diagnostics: [2024-03-10 11:17:07.993]Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
[2024-03-10 11:17:07.996]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137. 
[2024-03-10 11:17:07.997]Killed by external signal
```

I am running my application with the following configuration:

```bash
# Spark parameters
export driver_memory=16g
export num_executors=8
export executor_cores=7
export executor_memory=20g

# Jar file, input path, output path
export target="target/ObjectRecognition-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
export input_path="[...]"
export output_path="[...]"

spark-submit --class package.ObjectRecognition \
  --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory $driver_memory \
  --num-executors $num_executors --executor-memory $executor_memory --executor-cores $executor_cores \
 $target $input_path $output_path
```

**Some technical details:**
I am trying to run the application on a cluster that has 8 slaves and 1 master node. Each slave has around 25g of memory.

The input dataset is the coco-dataset-2017, which means that each file only occupies around 100~200kb.

I am using the yolov3 model to perform Object Recognition: each time a node is requested to perform detection it reads the network using `org.opencv.dnn.Net.readFromDarknet()`.
(I am uncertain if this last detail is useful).

As far as I understand from searching on internet the error 137 is caused by Out Of Memory.
I tried to "play" with the values for executor_memory and driver_memory in the bash script that runs my application but nothing changed.

EDIT: I also tried to repartition the input RDD - at first there were 150 partitions for an input of 123404 images. I tried with 300/500/600 partitions.

The error didn't change. Also, I tried to increase the MaxResultSize but this didn't fix the error as well.